# can any one tell me what exactly setInterval() method in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Can any one please tell me how the setInterval() in angular is working .is  java script  functionality they implement in angular js ?

Comment: Whhhataya mean?

Comment: This would have been a good opportunity to search "setInterval JavaScript" first and learn what it is.

Comment: @gvsk255 I think the issue you may be having is that the way you have your typescript configured is such that it doesn't recognise `setInterval` as a function. You may need to update you linting.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is a function that is exposed by the browser window as part of the global scope.  Angularjs just makes use of it like any other javascript code could.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval is a function that continually invokes a callback after every X milliseconds, where X is provided to setInterval.

// setInterval usage
function callback(){
  console.log("callback is called continuously");
}

var repeat = 3000;
setInterval(callback, repeat);

It will continue to run as long as your program is running.


Here's another example but with canceling setInterval
var num = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  num++;
  console.log("num:", num);
  if(num === 3){
    clearInterval(intervlId);
  }
}, 1000);

// output
num: 1
num: 2
num: 3
```